# Highcharts custom text right to left export

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Well my problem is that i have a chart and on it i have some custom text that has to be in the top right and top bottom corner of the chart im using `renderer.text('text', 600, 30).add();`

I first had it like `renderer.text('text', 600, 30).css('direction': 'rtl').add();`
this worked fine but when i exported it didn't recognize the stlye

then i tried to use `renderer.text('<span style="direction:rtl;">text</span>', 600, 30).add();`
this also worked only to show it on the page, but the exporting doesn't

Is there any way to fix this to work for exporting?

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nniicc/7Lwgarss/)

Comment: See information about [rtl](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization) - as you can see, suggested is to set `useHTML` option. However, exporting server doesn't export HTML&CSS - only SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to avoid the whole "CSS and exporting" issue for this particular problem is to use the bounding box of the text to place it correctly, instead of the CSS solution.

```
function (chart) { // on complete
    var rightTop = [590,85];
    var element = chart.renderer.text('This is a looooong text', 0, -100).add();
    var boundingBox = element.getBBox();
    element.destroy();
    chart.renderer.text('This is a looooong text', 
            rightTop[0] - boundingBox.width, 
            rightTop[1]).add();
}
```

Here the `rightTop` variable represents where we want it to be placed. Then the text is added (out of vision), we get the bounding box to know the size of it, and then destroy it. Then we recreate the text in the correct position.

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lwgarss/5/) for a demonstration of how it may work.

Comment: No problem. Consider my change @nniicc. Withdrawing `boundingBox.height` didn't make much sense.